# Pyqt4 MDI no clean mdiarea

Tags: pyqt4, mdi, mdichild

I am new to PyQt, I am developing an application like MDI, I use the QDesigner to build the forms (I come from Visual Basic), so far so good, but it is costing me horrors to run the application well, when I close a window, erase everything, but the frame remains on the mdi-area, click on the x and close. I attach the code.

With this I knock at the window:

```
def ordentrabajo(self):

    self.cot = FichaOrdenTrabajo()
    subwindow = QtGui.QMdiSubWindow()
    self.cot.mdiarea = self.ventana.mdiArea
    subwindow.setWidget(self.cot)
    subwindow.setGeometry(0, 0, 595, 490)
    self.ventana.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwindow)
    subwindow.showventana = self.cot.show()
```

And within the FichaOrdenTrabajo I close with:

```
def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):

    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('cerrar'))
    general.saveposic('ctrlordentrabajo', self.x(), self.y())
    self.subwindow.close = self.cdeta.close()
    self.cdeta.hide()
    # del self.subwindow
    self.subwindow = None
```

leaving the main window in this state:

[image: ventana principal]

The question is how to do so that when closing the mdi-area is clean?

Thank you